# Forced unwrapping of optional causes crash

Tags: swift

Am having trouble with this method; get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error.

```
func configureCheckmarkForCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withChecklistItem item:ChecklistItem) {
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as! UILabel

    if item.checked {
        label.text = "√"
    } else {
        label.text = ""
    }
}
```

How do I fix this to prevent it from crashing?
I have another method which is similar, and features a force unwrapped optional, and it causes no trouble:

```
func configureTextForCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withChecklistItem item:ChecklistItem) {
    let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
    label.text = item.text
}
```

Comment: Is `viewWithTag(1001)` is label are you sure?

Comment: I added mention of another method which features a force unwrapped optional which does not crash. Don't understand why this method causes trouble.

Comment: because tag is different for both.Just change your tag from 1001 to 1000.

Comment: Most likely there is no view with a tag of 1001. But you shouldn't be using this anyway, try subclassing `UITableViewCell` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The line which crashes is obvious:

```
let label = cell.viewWithTag(1001) as! UILabel
```

There are two reasons for the crash:

- the cell doesn't have a view with tag 1001
- the view with tag 1001 is not an UILabel

So check your design :

Make sure that **all** cells you pass thru this method have an associated view with tag 1001 and this view is an UILabel.

If that's not possible use optional bindings as described in the answer of Gerd Castan

The Swift language encourages developers to solve those issues at design or compile time to make the code more performant by dropping all dispensable type checks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
func configureTextForCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withChecklistItem item:ChecklistItem) {

    if let view = cell.viewWithTag(1000) {
        if let label = view as? UILabel {
            label.text = item.text
        } else {
            print ("view is of type \(view.classForCoder)")
        }
    }

}
```

it will not crash and will tell you when your assumption about your class is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may have put the *Label* into the wrong *cell* (in storyboard). As written in the other answers the *cell* does not have a *view* with your tag.

Example:
If you have some kind of view with a cell for the "overview" and another view with a cell for the "detail view", you may have put the Label into the "detail view", although its needed in the "overview" (or vice versa).